# Large Docker context slowing down docker-compose build

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, sbt

I have two images that use a two-stage build to build Scala code and copy the artifacts to a final image. To speed up the build, I copy my local `~/.ivy2` to the context directory and from there to the images (~1GB). Unfortunately this means that even when nothing has changed and the images don't need to be re-built, `docker-compose build` (or `docker build`) hangs for quite a while to copy Docker context. This happens twice of course, once for each image.

Is there any cleverer way to do this?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https gnupg2 &&\
    echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list &&\
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823 &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y sbt=1.1.6

COPY ivy-cache/ /root/.ivy2

COPY app/source/ /app/source

RUN cd /app/source &&\
    sbt assembly &&\
    cp target/scala-2.11/my-app-*.jar /app/my-app.jar

FROM gettyimages/spark:2.3.1-hadoop-3.0

COPY --from=0 /app/my-app.jar /app/my-app.jar

CMD ["spark-submit", "--master", "local", "/app/my-app.jar"]
```

Comment: What does the `~/ivy2` folder contain? Only dependencies? To answer if there are better ways to speed up the build, it could help if you provide the dockerfile.

Comment: How do you copy the directory? Have you tried `rsync`? We used it quite a lot to copy whole bare git repositories or composer libraries. Not clever, but it worked fine.

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk that is SBT's cache. Otherwise the build process will have to download all dependencies every time, which can take a long time. Dockerfile added.

Comment: @ygor Not sure how that could help here?

Comment: I was only fishing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 18.09, docker includes BuildKit. By itself, BuildKit will cache the previous context and only send over the differences with the equivalent of rsync in the background.

For this specific case, you can use some experimental features to mount in your dependency cache as the equivalent of a named volume using the `RUN --mount` syntax. The cache directory never makes it into the image, but is there for later builds, and when you pull in a new dependency it will behave just like a local build, downloading only the new dependencies.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM openjdk:8 as build

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https gnupg2 &&\
    echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list &&\
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823 &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y sbt=1.1.6

COPY app/source/ /app/source

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.ivy2 \
    cd /app/source &&\
    sbt assembly &&\
    cp target/scala-2.11/my-app-*.jar /app/my-app.jar

FROM gettyimages/spark:2.3.1-hadoop-3.0 as release

COPY --from=build /app/my-app.jar /app/my-app.jar

CMD ["spark-submit", "--master", "local", "/app/my-app.jar"]
```

To use BuildKit under 18.09, you can either export an environment variable:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

or update the engine with the new default in /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{ "features": {"buildkit": true} }
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem. I was hoping to share my local ivy cache, but this works too, a caveat being that it's slow the first time (as it downloads all dependencies). Still way better than before.

Comment: I had to extract the build process from `docker-compose` though because `docker-compose build` doesn't work with Buildkit.

Comment: The advice from the compose developer is to move builds out of the compose file since swarm mode doesn't perform builds. Best to have a ci/cd system building images and storing on a registry for others to use.

Comment: So is there a way to use my local ivy cache initially (first time) so that the whole cache is not downloaded?

Comment: You could run your original Dockerfile that you had before, but with buildkit enabled, and see performance improvements. No need to switch to the experimental features. The build context will be cached.

Comment: That seems to work, nice! Though, could you please clarify what `from` option does for cache mounts? I couldn't understand it from https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md

Comment: @lfk the `from` lets you mount other images, with `cache` as the type it looks like it initializes the cache. Treat cache types like a named volume, and from in this syntax like the image being used when you initialize that named volume. You could probably run a copy in a previous stage and use that as your cache, but that would probably result in 3 copies rather than 2.